Header files for types of contexts passed into eBPF programs
Files like /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_connect/format describe the type of context that is passed to an eBPF program that is attached to a certain tracepoint. Do corresponding definitions in C header files or tools that could turn the descriptions into such header files exist as well?

If you are talking about the connect syscall API, check with man connect.
If you are talking about how is the fomart file generated or can we find the header file for it , check include/trace/trace_events.h. Especially the file stage3_trace_output.h
